# why does this php code not crop my image?

Tags: php

I have this code which should generate part of this image: [My Minecraft skin (seriously, that is my image)](http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/figgycity50.png)

However, it does not generate. The image is not valid. My code:

```
<?php
$username = "figgycity50";
$skin_php_data = file_get_contents ("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/".$username.".png");
$skin = imagecreatefrompng ( $skin_php_data );
$hv = array('x' => 8, 'y' => 8, 'width' => 8, 'height' => 8);
$head = imagecrop($skin, $hv);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($head);
?>
```

Comment: Try: `error_reporting(e_all|e_strict)` - off: tip: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should not be using file_get_contents.

```
<?php
$username = "figgycity50";
$skin = imagecreatefrompng ( "http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/".$username.".png" );
$hv = array('x' => 8, 'y' => 8, 'width' => 8, 'height' => 8);
$head = imagecrop($skin, $hv);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($head);
?>
```

The document claims that imagecreatefrompng accepts a filename as its parameter. If fopen wrappers are enabled, you can use a URL.

https://www.php.net/imagecreatefrompng

Comment: odd, but this does not work. I checked my php.ini for fopen wrappers and they are on.

Comment: I tried loading your image it appears to be corrupt as well. Try another image.

Comment: tried to use minotar.net instead of the official skin repository. No corrupt, but white.